# How to select values as a list in PostgreSQL and Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, select

I have a table with values as given below:

```
Name  App_pgm_apply   status 
a        P1             AP
a        P3             DN
a        P5             AP
b        P2             PE
b        P3             AP
c        P1             AP
d        P2             DN
```

I want to select user with applied program as a list.

```
a   {P1,P3,P5}
b   {P2,P3}
c   {P1}
d   {P2}
```

Can someone tell me how to retrieve values as a list?

I saw this in SQL [here](http://www.sqlines.com/sybase-asa-to-sql-server/list) . But I didn't get how to use it PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a `array_agg` function:

```
SELECT   name, ARRAY_AGG(app_pgm_apply)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Oracle, on the other hand, has a [`listagg`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function:

```
SELECT   name, LISTAGG(app_pgm_apply, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY app_pgm_apply)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: for oracel can we separate list elements by comma?

Comment: @Rushikesh `listagg` has an optional delimiter parameter - I've edited my answer to add it, see there.

Comment: I have one more question. In my case, in select clause I have 30+ fields. Then do I need to add all fields in group by clause? Is there any optional way?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  Name,
  array_to_string(array_agg(App_pgm_apply), ',')) as pgms 
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY 
  Name
```